# Query takes too much time is there way to optimize it?

Tags: mysql, sql

The mysql query,

Kindly help me with the changes i can make to make the query run faster

```html
SELECT max("Domain"), 
max("LIcenseGen"),
max("Product"),
if( max("Domain") in 
           (select "Domain" 
            from "qAllCustomerDomain" 
            where "USERTYPE" != 'Registered'),'No','Yes') as 'LicenseStatus'
FROM "qRegistered" group by "Domain","LIcenseGen"
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you comment out the conditional if line and does performance improve?

Comment: "if( max("Domain") in (select "Domain" from "qAllCustomerDomain" where "USERTYPE" != 'Registered'),'No','Yes') as 'LicenseStatus'" is drag. use JOIN instead of it

Comment: What GA said - mysql is notoriously bad at handling subqueries.

Comment: I suggest reading up on `EXPLAIN` as a technique for improving query performance.

Comment: @GADeveloper can you help me with that

Comment: @RossBush yes. the performance improves considerabilily. executes in milli seconds now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding index on domain and usertype. That should speed up your query to great extent

Answer (score 1):

as it was suggested in comments

```
select main.*
       if (reg.Domain is NULL,'No','Yes') as 'LicenseStatus' 
from
    (SELECT max("Domain") as max_domain, 
           max("LIcenseGen"),
           max("Product")
    FROM "qRegistered" 
    group by "Domain","LIcenseGen") main
    LEFT JOIN (select "Domain" 
            from "qAllCustomerDomain" 
            where "USERTYPE" != 'Registered'
    ) reg on main.max_domain=reg.Domain
```

Comment: Instead of `IF` it would be preferable to use `CASE` `WHEN` `THEN` `ELSE` to make it portable on all SQL engines.

Comment: @Stavr00 I agree. I prefer to use CASE/WHEN but in this case IF was already used so it's easier to understand for the author